quasar responsive css classes - render content conditionally
I'd like to display some content based on the screen width.
Quasar has window width related css classes for that.
Displaying the content whenever the breakpoint is above md works:
 <div class="gt-md text-grey-11 text-h1">Hello</div>

But how do I use this conditionally?
With tailwind we can use the breakpoint as a prefix, like:
<div class="text-grey-100 sm:text-red-100"></div>

How to do that with Quasar?
